# Evaluate multiple expressions in a Thymeleaf attribute

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am a bit new to Thymeleaf, so apologies if this is a newb syntax mistake.
I am trying to have Thymeleaf execute multiple statements in the same `th:with` attribute.

```
<div th:with="url = ${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURL()}, url = ${url.substring(0, url.indexOf('error'))}"></div>
```

But this is not the correct syntax.

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "url = ${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURL()}, url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('error'))" (error/404:11)

Is this possible, and if so what is the correct syntax for what I'm trying to accomplish?

**EDIT**: There was a syntax error in the part below that I have fixed, and now I'm getting a different error.

Tried breaking it into two, but then it appears that the `url` variable is not populated correctly in the SpringEL expression.

```
<div th:with="url = ${#httpServletRequest.getRequestURL()}">
    <div th:with="url = ${url.substring(0, url.indexOf('error'))}"></div>
</div>
```

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "url = ${url.substring(0, url.indexOf('error')})" (error/404:12)
> Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: try without spaces maybe :)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your second example.  If your url variable doesn't have the string "error" in it, it returns -1 which causes **url.substring** to fail with the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I will refer to the second version.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm

`int indexOf(String str)`: Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring. If it does not occur as a substring, `-1` is returned.

So i think that `error` did not occur.

Then you are trying to do

```
url.substring(0,-1)
```

and you get an error.